# How to use web client in VB .Net

Tags: vb.net, webclient

Greatings, ive got a piece of code and i keep getting an error when executing the code in VB. The error says " 'Captcha' is not declared." . Enyone?## Heading ##

---

**The code:**

```
With New Net.WebClient
    Try
        Dim b() As Byte = .UploadFile(New System.Uri("127.0.0.1"), Captcha.Path)
        Captcha.Solution = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b).Split(CChar("|"))(5).ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Result.FailMessage = "Could not retrieve captcha response; " & ex.Message
        Exit Try
    End Try
End With
```

---

Comment: Why do you expect `Captcha` to exist?

Comment: basically im trying to send captcha from my program to Captcha Sniper and then receive the output, and someone gave me this code and said there were classes needed for it to work.

Comment: You need to understand what your code means before you can hope for it to work.  This won't help you at all.